# Binding data to html page - angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Im a bit of a newbie when it comes to web applications. I'm using spring MVC and trying to create a restful application with an angular front end.

My problem is that I want to use RestfulControllers throughout my application, but how do i render html files from this.

For example say i have

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndexPage() {
    return "Dashboard";
}
```

In a normal controller, upon hitting http://localhost:8080/ this would render Dashboard.html, however in RestControllers this is not the case, it just shows the string 'Dashboard'. How do i bind this data to a html/angular file -> what is the middle step im missing?

Thanks

Comment: Try to return `ModelAndView` object instead of String. You can use jsp, thymeleaf or any other view technology to generate the view.

Comment: In my humble opinion, you should do some more design work if you want to do down the angularjs route.  for that you would need to launch a html in the normal way in browser and then fetch the data (just the data) from spring controller by making it return a json (or any other format). Spring controller wont launch or redirect to any page. ResponseBody annotation could be utilised